# Plot graph with multiple y axis variable in r

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following data structure
[image]
I have plotted the graph of Date ( x axis) Vs TypeA / TypeB /….
How can I plot Date (x axis) vs multiple Types (like TypeA , TypeB - 2 lines. One for each).

The code currently used is

```
output$trendPlot1 <- renderPlotly({
    dataset1 <- reactive({
      data3[sample(nrow(data3) , 100 ),]
    })
    p <- ggplot(dataset1(), aes_string(x = "Date", y = input$y )) +
       ggtitle(paste0("Simple Cumulative Return of Stock over Time")) +
      # geom_point()
      geom_line()
    ggplotly(p) %>% 
      layout( autosize=TRUE)
  })
```

y (drop down list with different Types) is inputed by the user on the screen.I will have multiple selection drop down list and will be able to select different Types. (there are around 100 types in actual data). I want to plot only the ones types that are selected by the user and not the rest.
How can I pass multiple selections to the graph to be plotted on a single graph?

Comment: you'd need to melt your dataframe such that "TypeA..." will have a column by itself

Comment: Thanks Javier for looking at this. But I can have multiple types selected by the user and then only the selected types must be plotted in one graph.

Comment: Please post dput of your data rather than image. That'll be easier for us to reproduce the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken the sample dataset from the above answer.

1. Convert data from wide to long format so that the type can be filtered.
2. Use that to subset the data while ggplotting in server

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

Date <- c("29-Oct-2018", "28-Oct-2018", "27-Oct-2018", "26-Oct-2018")
TypeA <- rnorm(4, 5, 2)
TypeB <- rnorm(4, 5, 3)
TypeC <- rnorm(4, 5, 4)
df <- data.frame(Date = Date, TypeA = TypeA, TypeB = TypeB, TypeC = TypeC)

wide_df <- df %>% gather(Type,Value,2:4)


ui <- fluidPage(


  selectInput(inputId = "type",
              label = "",
              choices = unique(wide_df$Type),
              multiple = TRUE),

  plotOutput("first_plot")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$first_plot <- renderPlot({

    wide_df %>% 
      filter(Type %in% input$type) %>% 
    ggplot() +
      geom_point(aes(Date, Value, color = Type))

  })




}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Than you .. works perfectly .converted geom_point to geom_line

Answer (score 0):

Since the actual data, was not provided (image can't be reproduced), I've used a sample data to explain. You need to convert the data to plot to long format using `melt` from `reshape2` package. Sample code given below. Do the modifications as required.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

Date <- c("29-Oct-2018", "28-Oct-2018", "27-Oct-2018", "26-Oct-2018")
TypeA <- rnorm(4, 5, 2)
TypeB <- rnorm(4, 5, 3)
TypeC <- rnorm(4, 5, 4)
df <- data.frame(Date = Date, TypeA = TypeA, TypeB = TypeB, TypeC = TypeC)

plotdf <- melt(df, id.vars = "Date")
print(ggplot(plotdf, aes(value, Date, colour = variable)) + geom_point() + 
        ggtitle(paste0("Simple Cumulative Return of Stock over Time")) +
        theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
        guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hello Snair1519 , I will share the actual data in a while. But in mean time , this was not my expected result. I would want the user to decide which type he would like to view in the graph. In my actual data there are 100+ types so the user would want to see only a few at a time by selecting it on the screen. How can I pass this multiple selection to the graph ?

Comment: @user1606540 Instead of all TypeA, TypeB, TypeC, you want just a selected list which the user should select?

Comment: @amrrs .Yes. TypeA , TypeB , TypeC ….TypeZ will be displayed to the user on the screen in a multiselect dropdown box. The user might select only one (e.g TypeC)[This graph works with my original code]. The user can select multiple too (e.g TypeA , TypeL , TypeY , TypeZ). The graph should show 4 lines on single xaxis , one for each type selected by the user. input$y is my input from User on Ui